# AWS SDK v3 - How to get TypeScript to compile the construction of DynamoDB client with custom timeout?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

It seems that in AWS SDK v3, in order to construct a DynamoDB client with custom timeout you need to first create a `NodeHttpHandler` and pass it as a `requestHandler` in the constructor of the DynamoDB Client like so:

```
import { DynamoDBClient } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { NodeHttpHandler } from '@aws-sdk/node-http-handler';

const requestHandler = new NodeHttpHandler({ requestTimeout: DYNAMO_DB_TIMEOUT });
const dynamoDbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ requestHandler });
```

This solution can be seen in answers such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77324334/1082326

However if I do that, then TypeScript displays the following error:

```
Types of property 'requestHandler' are incompatible.
  Type 'NodeHttpHandler' is not assignable to type 'HttpHandler'.
    Type 'NodeHttpHandler' is missing the following properties from type '{ updateHttpClientConfig(key: never, value: never): void; httpHandlerConfigs(): {}; }': updateHttpClientConfig, httpHandlerConfigs ts(2345)
```

Given that this is the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77324334/1082326) on how to create a DynamoDB client with custom timeout, how do I get TypeScript to compile this correctly without resorting to using `@ts-ignore`?

I'm using:

- NodeJS 18
- "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.441.0"
- "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler": "^3.374.0"
- "@aws-sdk/types": "^3.433.0" (dev dependency)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NodeHttpHandler` should be from `@smithy`:

```
const { DynamoDBClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { NodeHttpHandler } = require("@smithy/node-http-handler");

var dynamodbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
    connectionTimeout: 2000,
    requestTimeout: 1000
 })
});
```